# Understand breakpoints calculations from ericportis.com (srcset-sizes)

Tags: css, responsive-design, breakpoints

Example **1x, after breakpoint** from [this article.](http://ericportis.com/posts/2014/srcset-sizes/)
`640px / (33,3vw x 1x) = 1920px = 120em`

I don't understand this expression.
I thought that `1vw = 1%` so
`640px / 33,3% = 213,12px`
and it's different than 1920px.

How it was calculated?

I know that `33.3` is a result of `100/3` but the expression in my opinion is incorrect. The only way to get `1920` in this case is multiply 640 by 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Article author here. Math with `vw` units (and percentages!) can get a bit confusing... `33.3vw`, as you say, is equal to 33.3% of the width of viewport, aka ⅓ of the viewport width. `640px` ÷ ⅓ = `640px` × 3 = `1920px`.